# How to return something as a sentence in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of OCCUPATIONS and i have to print out this sentence
`There are total [occupation_count] [occupation]s.` using only MySql,how should i do that?

Comment: Use [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CONCAT(string1, string2, ...)`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php):

```
CONCAT('There are total ', [occupation_count], [occupation], 's')
```

Comment: Thanks for thy answer homes

Comment: Happy to help. Peace and love brother.